# To Become a Data Analyst?

Tags: data-cleaning, data-analysis, beginner, analysis

currently I am in year4 and also working as a product owner who would want to shift the occupation path to data analyst in banking, but the problem is **I don't know where to start**. May I have some suggestions/opinions on what should I learn and if possible kindly share some studying materials or resources, would be a big help. Thank you...

Comment: Hi @Hunter, welcome to the site. I think it would be better if you tried in other sites like reddit, because here at datascience.stackexchange.org, we focus on actual data science questions instead of career advice opinion-based questions; you can check the [help center](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). I suggest you [google about the topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=data+analyst+career+advice+reddit), as you will find many previous questions like yours with a lot of information.

Comment: As noe mentioned, you're better off seeking advice from other forums. I recommend going to Reddit and visiting subreddits like r/cscareerquestions r/DataScienceJobs and maybe a "tech careers" subreddit specific to the country you live in as it might have relevant information.